# Rails 4: ActiveRecord => can't "select" has_one :through field from db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1, has-one-through

I am trying to retrieve one field from a "has_one :through" association. Assuming I have the following model:

```
class CreatePersons < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :person do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.date   :age
    end
  end

  def change
    create_table :location do |t|
      t.decimal     :longitude
      t.decimal     :latitude
      t.string      :city
      t.string      :state

      t.references  :person
    end
  end

  def change
    create_table :forecasts do |t|
      t.timestamp   :time
      t.text        :summary
      t.decimal     : precipitation

      t.references    :location

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

... and the following model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :person
  belongs_to  :forecast
end

class Forecast < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :locaiton
  has_one    :person,    :through => :location
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

.. and I want to make query using ActiveRecord that pulls out ONLY the persons first name based on the forecast (i know its stupid, but this is just an excercise); so something like this:

```
# i realize this is a bad query, i'm putting this here to make my question stronger
Forecast.where("percipitation > ?", 1.5).select(:first_name)
```

or in SQL terms

```
select first_name from forecast fc
inner join locaiton loc on loc.id = fc.location_id
inner join person on person.id = loc.person_id
where precipitation > 1.5
```

SO I have tried something like this:

```
Forecast.joins(:person).where("percipitation > ?", 1.5).select(:person)

# Forecast.joins(:person).where("percipitation > ?", 1.5).select(:person).to_sql

#  select 'person' from forecast fc
#  inner join locaiton loc on loc.id = fc.location_id
#  inner join person on person.id = loc.person_id
#  where fc.percipitation > 1.5
```

this returns me empty instances of the Forecast object

so then I tried this:

```
Forecast.joins(:person).where("percipitation > ?", 1.5).select("person.first_name")

# Forecast.joins(:person).where("percipitation > ?", 1.5).select("person.first_name").to_sql

#  select 'person.first_name' from forecast fc
#  inner join locaiton loc on loc.id = fc.location_id
#  inner join person on person.id = loc.person_id
#  where fc.percipitation > 1.5
```

however, this also results in a colleciton of empty Forecast objects

HOWEVER, doing this results in exactly what i want, **but this is already after the db has been queried**:

```
result = Forecast.joins(:person).where("precipitation > ?", 1.5)

result.each do |forecast|

  puts forecast.person.first_name # => "John", "Bob", "Jim"

end
```

**Why can't I get just the first_name out of the DB using select and pull only first_name out of the database?** I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: Also, I understand that I could potentially add a scope, but from my understanding scope is just going to give me the ability to run a manual query and provide me with syntactic sugar such as select("person.first_name") as per: file:///Users/tomek/Library/Application%20Support/Dash/DocSets/Ruby_on_Rails_4/Ruby%20on%20Rails.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope.

But I'm trying to figure out why I can't project via select, but I can in an each method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why your solution works at all.

Do it this way:

```
Forecast.where("precipitation > ?", 1.5).joins(:person).pluck("person.first_name")
```

It will return array of first names.

If you really need to use `select` (to get a scope):

```
Forecast.where("precipitation > ?", 1.5).joins(:person).select("person.first_name")
```

Comment: Why do you say: "I don't know why your solution works at all." ??

Comment: Because you should specify what table you want to join. You are trying to select person first_name from Forecast, but you don't specify the person table in join clause. ActiveRecord should raise an exception, because it will try to find first_name column in the forecasts table.

Comment: Ok, but I have a has_one clause on Forecast to Person, doesn't that help to make the join automatically?

Comment: As far as I know, NO. I have tested this.

Comment: Ok, I just tested it too and I am baffled, you are correct, it will not give you the relationship automatically!

Comment: OMG, ok... it appears I have led you astray, and I apologize. Basically, when I recreated my model in the StackOverflow window; I forgot to add the .joins(). You are absolutely correct, it will not work. Please pardon the foolish move, but I ended up confusing myself too.

Comment: Yes it solved it. Thanks very much. I saw that I can do something like .select("person.first_name"), but felt it a very weak reference, so I figured i was doing something wrong. I'm used to Entity Framework in .NET which does strong (static) typing via backed XML files. So "person.first_person" just felt weird. Thanks for conversation, i learned a lot.